# Check updated state of GET request in useEffect Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-effect

When I create an item and click save, I would like when I return to the page it automatically updates with what I just created. So that my useEffect detects the changes that have just arrived at the level of the GET request.

But I tried everything, I tried to put the variable `garden` in the array of useEffect but it makes an infinite loop of GET request, I also tried to put `setGarden` it does not make an infinite loop but it does not update automatically, I have to reload the page...

Here is the code :

```js
const [garden, setGarden] = useState([]);
const [plot, setPlot] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const navigation = useNavigation();

  const gardenData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
    const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(user);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `http://127.0.0.1/api/garden?user=${parsedUserData.user.id}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Token ${parsedUserData.token}`,
          },
        },
      );
      if (response.status === 200) {
        navigation.navigate('LogScreen');
        setGarden(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
        try {
          const plotResponse = await axios.get(
            `http://127.0.0.1/api/plots?garden=${response.data[0].id}`,
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Token ${parsedUserData.token}`,
              },
            },
          );
          if (plotResponse.status === 200) {
            setPlot(plotResponse.data);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          alert(e);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Erreur ' + e);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    gardenData();
  }, []);
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use an indication to make sure the gardenData function in ran once. Either you can initialize one of your state or even you can use a complete new state This is only run the code once.

```html
    const [garden, setGarden] = useState([]);
    const [plot, setPlot] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [FirstRun, setFirstRun] = useState(true);
    const navigation = useNavigation();

      const gardenData = async () => {
        if(!FirstRun) return;
        setFirstRun(false);
        setLoading(true);
        const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(user);
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(
            `http://127.0.0.1/api/garden?user=${parsedUserData.user.id}`,
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Token ${parsedUserData.token}`,
              },
            },
          );
          if (response.status === 200) {
            navigation.navigate('LogScreen');
            setGarden(response.data);
            setLoading(false);
            try {
              const plotResponse = await axios.get(
                `http://127.0.0.1/api/plots?garden=${response.data[0].id}`,
                {
                  headers: {
                    Authorization: `Token ${parsedUserData.token}`,
                  },
                },
              );
              if (plotResponse.status === 200) {
                setPlot(plotResponse.data);
              }
            } catch (e) {
              alert(e);
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('Erreur ' + e);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      };

      useEffect(() => {
if(FirstRun)
{
        gardenData();
}
// your code here

}, [garden]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but on the contrary I don't want the useEffect to execute only once, I want that with each change in the `garden` variable and that of `plot` (so each time that there are new elements in the query), the code is re-executed

Comment: You want to run the UseEffect hook every time value of garden and plot is updated which means you want to run gardenData function every time value of garden is updated? gardenData function updates the value of garden every time so the UseEffect will be a deadlock. What exactly do you want to happen once the value of garden is updated?

Comment: In fact in another page I have a function which allows to create the gardens and the plots, but in this page I have a function which recovers the garden and the plots except that with each creation of garden or plot I am obliged to reload the application to get its new items, they do not appear automatically, how can I do?